# Vue.js 2.0 and Meteor JS

Tags: javascript, html, meteor, vue.js, vuejs2

I am developing a simple app using Vue.js and Meteor. I get a very strange error :
'**Cannot find element 'widget'**' even though in my opinion it shouldn't give this kind of error. These are my files:
**Main.html**

```
<head>
<title>vue-blaze</title>
</head>

<body>
<h1>Welcome to Meteor!</h1>
{{> vue_demo}}
</body>

<template name="vue_demo">
<div id="app">
</div>
</template>
```

**Main.js**

```
import { Template } from 'meteor/templating';
import { Session } from 'meteor/session';

import './main.html';


import {Vue} from 'meteor/akryum:vue';
import widget from '/imports/ui/Widget.vue';

//window.onload=function(){
var vm = new Vue({
el: '#widget',
render:h=>h(widget)
});
//}
```

**Widget.vue**

```
<template>
<div id="widget">
<div>Hello {{msg1}}!</div>
<input v-model="name" placeholder="Enter your name" />
</div>
</template>

<script>
import {Session} from 'meteor/session'
export default {
data() {
return {
  msg1: 'Somebody'
}
}
}
</script>

<style scoped>
.widget {
background: #a0ddc4;
padding: 12px;
border-radius: 3px;
width: 300px;
border-bottom: solid 1px #40b883;
}

input {
display: block;
margin: 4px 0;
width: 100%;
box-sizing: border-box;
border: none;
padding: 6px 12px;
border-radius: 3px;
}
</style>
```

I have to mention that everything was working before updating to Vue 2.0.3.

Answer (score 0):

In your vue instance you are passing `#widget1 to the`el` option like this

```
var vm = new Vue({
el: '#widget',
render:h=>h(widget)
});
//}
```

But in your html you have the element with id `app` so pass `#app` to `el`

```
var vm = new Vue({
el: '#app',
render:h=>h(widget)
});
//}
```

Comment: [Vue warn]: Cannot find element: #app @VamsiKrishna

Comment: @Roberto place the whole `template` element in the `<body></body>` tag

Comment: If I put the template in the body tag it says "No such template: vue_demo" which makes sense since it's going to search for a template outside the body tag and it's not there anymore. The "Cannot find element #app " error persists though. @VamsiKrishna